# Match Q&A with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a set of questions and a set of answers. Each answer is the only correct answer for one question. I need to highlight the right selected question or answer when it's clicked.

For example:

- When a question is clicked, change that specific question's class to "active" (so the css changes)
- When an answer is clicked, change that specific answer's class to "active"

Here's the main page:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleQAClick = this.handleQAClick.bind(this)
    this.toggleColour = this.toggleColour.bind(this)

    this.state = {
        questions: [],
        active: true
    }
}
```

...

```
handleQAClick = (type, id) => {
    console.log(id)
    console.log(type)
    this.toggleColour(id)
}

toggleColour = id => {
    this.setState({active: !this.state.active})
    console.log('should change colour')
}
```

...

```
<Card>
    {this.state.questions.length 
        ? (
            <List>
                {this.state.questions.map(question => (
                    <ListItem key={question._id}>
                        <MatchItem
                            id={question._id}
                            type="question"
                            active={this.state.active}
                            text={question.question}
                            handleClick={this.handleQAClick}
                        />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
        )
        : ('No questions found')                        
    }
</Card>
<Card>
    {this.state.questions.length 
        ? (
            <List>
                {this.state.questions.map(question => (
                    <ListItem key={question._id}>
                        <MatchItem
                            id={question._id}
                            type="answer"
                            text={question.option1}
                            handleClick={this.handleQAClick}
                        />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
        )
        : ('No questions found')                        
    }
</Card>
```

Here's the MatchItem component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export class MatchItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={`match-item${this.props.active ? "-active" : ""}`} data-id={this.props.id} data-type={this.props.type} onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(this.props.id, this.props.type)}>
                {this.props.text}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this can be:

- Assign a unique id to each Card (Question).
- Change classes this way

  `<Component 
    className={this.state.currQuestion === question.id ? 'active' : null} 
    onClick={this.handleClick(question.id)}
  />`
- And you can manage states this way:

  `handleClick = (id) => {
      this.setState({
         currQuestion: id
      })
  }`